# Clever ways to generate JSON blob from PostgresSQL database schema

Tags: json, postgresql, schema

I'm looking for clever ways to generate a large json object of our small postgresql database schema. Anyone have any experience doing this? Is there some simple queries we can write in postgres? I know json is pretty well supported. Just looking for table names, columns in those tables, and their column types.

Something like

```
{ "schema": [ {"books": 
{ "columns": [ { "id": {"type": "int"}... ] }}]}
```

Edit: Output format isn't mega important, just looking for ways to generate a json object of the database schema.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select jsonb_build_object(table_schema, 
                          jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(table_name, columns))) as schema_info
from (
  select t.table_schema, t.table_name, 
         jsonb_build_object('columns', jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(c.column_name, jsonb_build_object('type', c.data_type)) 
                                                 order by c.ordinal_position)
                           ) as columns
  from information_schema.tables t
    join information_schema.columns c 
       on c.table_schema = t.table_schema 
      and c.table_name = t.table_name
  where t.table_schema in ('public', 'foo', 'bar')
  group by t.table_schema, t.table_name
) t1
group by table_schema;
```

This will return one JSON value for each schema listed in the inner most where clause. You can further aggregate them if you want. You probably also want to tweak the retrieval of the data type a bit more to e.g. include the length for VARCHAR columns